# Jquery: Lined up divs showing offset top as not same

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am relatively new to javascript and the I am scratching my head for this issue. I have bunch of spans, all in the same line. But when I get the top of all the span elements and compare, its saying its not the same, but in the console I can see that the value is the same for all spans which is 8. Am i missing something here.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (Math.floor($("#menu1").offset().top) === Math.floor($("#menu2").offset().top) === Math.floor($("#menu3").offset().top)) {
    console.log("equal");
  } else {
    console.log($("#menu1").offset().top);
    console.log($("#menu2").offset().top);
    console.log($("#menu3").offset().top);
    console.log('not equal');
  }
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: block;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

span {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  /* float: right; */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
  <span id='menu1'>item1</span>
  <span id='menu2'>item2</span>
  <span id='menu3'>item3</span>
  <span id='menu4'>item4</span>
  <span id='menu5'>item5</span>
  <span id='menu6'>item6</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `console.log(8 === 8 === 8)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to your compound comparison.

Taking it step by step, the `if` condition equates to this:

```
if (8 === 8 === 8)
```

After the first comparison this becomes:

```
if (true === 8)
```

Clearly, this condition will not pass.

An alternative is to build an array of the `top` offset values and use `every()` to check if they are all identical:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $spans = $('.container .menu');
  let tops = $spans.map((i, el) => $(el).offset().top).get();
  let allIdentical = tops.every(t => $spans.first().offset().top);

  console.log(allIdentical ? 'equal' : 'not equal');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <span class="menu">item1</span>
  <span class="menu">item2</span>
  <span class="menu">item3</span>
  <span class="menu">item4</span>
  <span class="menu">item5</span>
  <span class="menu">item6</span>
</div>
```

You could alternatively use a single loop using `each()`, comparing the current `top` to the previous. As soon as there's a discrepancy you know they are not all the same.

Which method is best for you depends entirely on your use case.

Comment: Ouch, thats embarassing. I overlooked that true === 8 comparison. Thanks a lot Rory. Lesson learnt. And also how to edit a question on SO :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)